# videojs basic implementation within a function

Tags: javascript, video.js, video-player

I would like to implement a basic code which runs videojs(http://videojs.com/getting-started/) upon a click. Implementing without a function works. But when I make it within a function (create DOM elements and attach them to the body), it does not. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0.3/video.js"></script>

        <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) 
            <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>-->
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = 'hello'></div>

            <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
            poster="" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="Selena_Gomez_Same_Old_Love.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
                <source src="" type='video/webm'>

                </video>

                <a href="javascript:playVideo()">Click me for playing the video</a>
                <script>
                    function playVideo(){
                        var video_element = document.createElement("VIDEO");
                        video_element.id= 'my-video';

                        video_element.class = 'video-js';

                        video_element.controls = 'auto';

                        video_element.setAttribute('preload','auto');

                        video_element.setAttribute('width','640');

                        video_element.setAttribute('height','264');







        //source
        var source_element = document.createElement("SOURCE");
        source_element.src='Selena_Gomez_Same_Old_Love.mp4';
        source_element.type= 'video/mp4';

        document.body.appendChild(video_element);
        document.body.appendChild(source_element);

    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
video_element.appendChild(source_element);
document.body.appendChild(video_element);
```